# Docker swarm: how does load balancing work

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I run a service in swarm mode. I have one manager and two worker nodes and the service has 6 replicas divided on the three nodes. I can reach my service with `manager:8080`, `worker1:8080` , `worker2:8080` without any problem.

Now, when I drain or shutdown worker2, `worker2:8080` still works, that's what I expected. However, when I drain the manager ... `manager:8080` is not reachable anymore. Why could this be?

I wanted to use swarm as a load balancer with high availability.

My manager has a domain so when I open `domain:8080` and the container on the manager are down due whatever reason it should redirect to one of the workers as I understand it. Is this even possible? Or do I have to assign the domain to the workers?

edit:

i start the service with:

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml --with-registry-auth <service_name>

my compose file:
```

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  portal:
    image: image-from-gitlab-registry:latest
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    deploy:
      replicas: 6
    networks:
      - network
    restart: always
  redis:
    image: redis:6.0.1
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
    networks:
      - network
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
networks:
  network:
```

Comment: Could you share the command you used to start the service?

Comment: docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml --with-registry-auth <service_name>. compose file is in my post. thanks!